# Using column name as result title on 2 or more tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have searched for a while but havent found a solution. I have 2 mysql tables. **object** and **meta**. objects describes pages, posts, categories and stuff

```
table object
----------
id    type
```

additional information about each object is stored in table meta

```
table meta
-----------------------------------------
id    object_id    meta_key    meta_value
```

If i have 1 object with id 1 and my two tables looks like this

```
object     |  meta
---------  |  -------------------------
1    post  |  1    1   title    a title
              2    1   content  a content
```

Is there a way to produce an output like this

```
object_id    type    title    content
-------------------------------------
1            post    a title  a content
```

even if there are 10, 20 or more fields? Here is an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b45ca/21) (edited) link. Thank you.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query - you might also look at pivoting but in general issues of data display are best resolved in application code.

Comment: thank you i have added a link to sqlfiddle.

Comment: are all the field names, even if they are 20 or more, known in advance (such that they can be hard coded in a query)?

Comment: no they arent, i have updated the link i forgot to change the query. thats my actual query.

Answer (score 1):

Try ...

```
select o.id, o.type, om.title, om.content
from object o left join (
  select object_id,
    max(case when meta_key = 'title' then meta_value end) as title,
    max(case when meta_key = 'content' then meta_value end) as content
  from object_meta
  group by object_id) om on o.id = om.object_id
```

Comment: thats a real nice idea, thanks for my new skill ;) but unfortunately it doesnt give the expected result. anyway,thank you

Comment: If it's about the missing `type`-attribute, see edited post.

Comment: it only works for title and content, as i said for my bad i cant use hardcoded keywords. i would need something like ´max(case when meta_key then meta_value end) as meta_key´ so the meta_key should be the heading of the column. sorry for my bad english.